# SSRS-2016 Redirect for Specific Traffic

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Is there a way to redirect SSRS - 2016 to a specific folder depending on the origin URL? For example, if the origin were: http://originsite.com/Reports.aspsx

I would want the report viewer to land on folder: /SpecificFolder and **NOT** on the Home folder.

For example:  I want all traffic hitting the SSRS machine from a particular URL to direct to a particular folder of my choosing.

Comment: Can you add more details of what you're trying to do? Are you trying to create a link in one of the objects within the report and direct it to the specific folder?

Comment: I added text to the post.